# Showing code chunk name in output in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

As known in RMarkdown code chunks can be named like this:

````
```{r chunkname}

plot(x,y)

```
````

Is it possible to showing chunkname in output document?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `knitr::opts_current$get()$label`

example:

````
```{r cars}
library(knitr)
opts_current$get()$label
plot(cars)
```
````

It will also work outside of a chunk, in an inline r code. It will then output the label of the last chunk.

You can of course save the labels in a vector to use them later, for instance with a custom hook:

````
```{r knitr_setup}
library(knitr)
ll <- opts_current$get()$label
knit_hooks$set(label_list = function(before, options, envir) {
    if(before) ll <<- c(ll,opts_current$get()$label)
})
opts_chunk$set(label_list=TRUE)
```
````

`ll` will then contain the list of chunk labels. However, you cannot access the names of chunks not yet ran.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any global option which opens all chunk name within the document?