# In rmarkdown, can one obtain the chunk ID inside the R-code of that chunk?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to obtain the ID (chunk name, chunk number, or both) in the R-code inside of that chunk. Is there a way to do this? Thank you sincerely!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer when searching for 'chunk label' instead of 'chunk ID':

````
```{r this_label}
library(knitr)
print(opts_current$get()$label)
```
````

Found the answer here: [Showing code chunk name in output in RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038607/showing-code-chunk-name-in-output-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: so should I mark this question a duplicate of the question you found useful since the answer is the same ?

Comment: Please do. I don't know exactly how to do that.